# HTML5 Canvas element behaving differently on various OS and platforms

Tags: windows, html, macos, canvas

A rails 4.2 application is configured to capture a signature via [signature-pad](https://github.com/thread-pond/signature-pad).

```
  <div class="sig sigWrapper">
    <canvas class="pad" width="900" height="195"></canvas>
    <input class="output" type="hidden" name="signature[signature]" id="signature_signature" />
  </div>
```

Trials have been conducted on a Mac and an original series Surface 3.  results were - according to an eye test - similar. And very acceptable.

However, a further set of testing with:

1. macBook Pro
2. Surface 3, under Windows 10. Chrome browser.
3. ASUS e402S with Turcom pen and tablet via USB, under Windows 10. Chrome browser

is now returning very different results.  The signatures generated on both Windows 10 screen are very jagged (and get saved that way).  I managed to use the Turcom pen tablet on the MBP (Mavericks complained a bit, but played along) is much smoother.

This points to a configuration issue under Windows 10, with the added head-scratcher of having seen a Surface3 produce at the same quality of the MacBook.

How can this be overcome?

**Update**

Using Edge has no jagged [ahem] edges.  So this points to a Chrome setting.

Comment: You problem probably lies in your js scripts rather than in the html markup, don't you think so ?

Comment: Definitely not an html issue, but a js one. Yet: "Why the different behaviour between browsers then?"  Conditionally setting js based on browser detection is not a preferred avenue...  I have now found a few sources that confirm anti-aliasing issues in the Chrome browser.  For this application's purposes, browser choice can be directed and thus by avoiding Chrome, we avoid this issue. Lower overall cost.

Comment: But how do you expect us to be able to help you if you don't show us the relevant part of the code ? You provided an HTML code block, but we all know this as nothing to do with your symptoms. Without an [MCVE], we can't help you and your question is off-topic...